# Skipping from Within a Nested Loop

Tags: vba

what i am trying to do is check if the value is between the values of two columns and if the value is inside then put a "1" in the cell and if not a "0" i alredy try with the continue and with the next j but it gives me a "next without a for". I know this has a simple solution but assistance be appreciated. Thanks

```
For i = 1 To ll
     For j = 1 To t
   If Cells(j + 1, 12).Value >= Cells(i + 1, 9).Value And Cells(j + 1, 12).Value< Cells(i + 1, 10).Value Then
Cells(j + 1, 13).Value = 1
Next j
  Else
   Cells(j + 1, 13).Value = 0
        Next i
            End If
```

`

Comment: Well your if statement cannot start inside the loop and end outside it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `Exit For`

```
For i = 1 To ll
    For j = 1 To t
        If Cells(j + 1, 12).Value >= Cells(i + 1, 9).Value And Cells(j + 1, 12).Value < Cells(i + 1, 10).Value Then
            Cells(j + 1, 13).Value = 1
            Exit For
        Else
            Cells(j + 1, 13).Value = 0
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

---

But I think you need to flip the loops. Otherwise in the end the only value that would be represented is when i = 11

```
For j = 1 To t
    For i = 1 To 11
        If Cells(j + 1, 12).Value >= Cells(i + 1, 9).Value And Cells(j + 1, 12).Value < Cells(i + 1, 10).Value Then
            Cells(j + 1, 13).Value = 1
            Exit For
        Else
            Cells(j + 1, 13).Value = 0
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

Comment: when you put Exit For the j return to be 1 and it check again and move the value to 1 to 0 all over again

Answer (score 1):

you're nesting if then else with for loop: this is the problem with your code.

```
For i = 1 To ll
    For j = 1 To t
        If (Cells(j + 1, 12).Value >= Cells(i + 1, 9).Value And Cells(j + 1, 12).Value< Cells(i + 1, 10).Value) Then 
            Cells(j + 1, 13).Value = 1
        Else
            Cells(j + 1, 13).Value = 0
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: when the i goes one up is not checking all the values in the column so it puts 0 when it must go a 1

Comment: can you provide a sample ?